# Not restart section numbering after each part in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, numbering, context

I just want to follow section numbers from the previous section. In the example text:

```
\starttext
\part{First part}

\section{1st section}
    
\part{Second part}

\section{2nd section}

\stoptext
```

ConTeXt numbers `2nd section` as `1` (see images) and I want `2` [image][image]

Comment: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineresetset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is this

```
\defineresetset[default][1,1,0][1] %% reset part, chapter, but not section
\setuphead[sectionresetset=default]
```

Comment: It seems that `1, 1, 0` affects also `subject`. That is, subject is treated as section. Anyone has a solution for that?